# How do I upgrade from cordova android 3.2 to 3.3 with eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Following the latest instructions from the [docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_upgrading.md.html#Upgrading%20Android) I ran the update command with the cordova cli.  I also updated eclipse and the android tools to API 19 as requested.

In the docs it says "IDE users will need to import the newly added MyProject-CordovaLib project into their workspace."  However, when I go to eclipse and import the library, I don't know where it is.  If I import the CordovaLib folder that is within the android folder, it comes up as "null-CordovaLib"  And I still get build errors.

Can someone help me out here and provide me with the instructions to get this going?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you tell me where is that latest lib , bz [here](http://phonegap.com/install/) i am only able to see latest 2.9.1

Comment: just to be clear, I'm using cordova, not phonegap: http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2013/12/16/cordova-330.html

Answer (score 1):

I am also seeing similar behavior except the build error goes away when I import null-CordovaLib.

As a workaround, try recreating the project rather than upgrading it and then copy your html assets to the newly created project.

It might also help if you post the text of the error's you are seeing or the error log view.